# MC Bedrock Server with existing world on Raspberry Pi4

Tags: pi-4

Me and my friends have a MC PE survival world, and we can only play when I am online (As the game is on my device). I was looking into putting the game onto a raspberry pi4 so anyone can play whenever, regardless if I am online or not.

My main question is this: Is it possible to create a server on Raspberry Pi with an existing world?

My google searches have only turned up things that you cannot import old worlds into, you have to start new. I also want to be able to download the world off the server and play it from the device (And especially take backups). There would be a max of 5-6 players, so nothing extreme.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is your question really Raspberry Pi specific? ... have you tried to copy the world files from one server to another server?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to set this up on a Pi, Minecraft for Raspberry Pi is different than MC bedrock (I think) and It does not seam to work with MC PE.